# Vue js computed result not accurate

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to implement a vote button with vue js, when user click "Vote" will send axios request to server and store the data, then return json back. Same with unvote.
I also check if the user is voted, the button should change to Unvote like facebook.
So far the vote and unvote button is work correctly.
But i found a problems which is the voted features is not working. If user voted, after refresh page it will change back to "Vote", but it should be Unvote. But if the button was clicked, in database will showing the vote was deleted. Mean it should be problems of computed. But i am struggle on it since i not really know vue js.

This is my vue components.

```
<template>

<a href="#" v-if="isLiked" @click.prevent="unlike(comment)">
    <span>UnVote</span>
</a>

<a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="like(comment)">
    <span>Vote</span>
</a>
```

```
<script>
export default{
    props: ['comment','liked'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            isLiked: '',
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/comment/'+ this.comment.id +'/check', {})
            .then((response) => {
                this.liked = response.data;//here will get json "true" or "false"

            });

        this.isLiked = this.liked ? true : false;
    },
    computed: {
        isLike() {
            return this.liked;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        like(comment) {
            axios.post('/comment/'+ comment.id +'/like')
                .then(response => this.isLiked = true)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },
        unlike(comment) {
            axios.post('/comment/'+ comment.id +'/unlike')
                .then(response => this.isLiked = false)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component instance does not have a `liked` data property and you should not attempt to set `prop` values (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Also, you are attempting to set the `isLiked` value outside of the asynchronous operation which will not work how you think.

Just set the `isLiked` property...

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('/comment/'+ this.comment.id +'/check', {})
        .then((response) => {
            this.isLiked = response.data; //here will get json "true" or "false"
        });
},
```

Your `isLike` computed property is also never used.